# IllegalArgumentException when I try UnsortedReadableList.loadFrom(Vector)

Tags: java, blackberry, illegalargumentexception

The following code:

```
UnsortedReadableList collection = new UnsortedReadableList();
Vector messages = new Vector();

// ApplicationMessageImpl is simple implementation of 
// net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationMessage interface
messages.addElement(new ApplicationMessageImpl("bla-bla"));
collection.loadFrom(messages);
```

produce `IllegalArgumentException`
[image]

Can someone help me to understand why? I can't see any details in exception

Update

[image]

Comment: collection_ and collection.loadFrom(messages). Please confirm whether it is a typo mistake : collection and collection_

Comment: Stacktrace attached but I'm not thinking that it will be helpful. The typo mistake has been fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`UnsortedReadableList.loadFrom()`'s JavaDoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/collection/util/UnsortedReadableList.html#loadFrom%28java.lang.Object%29) states about the collection parameter:

> collection - New contents for this list; should be a ReadableSet, a
>   ReadableList, an Object array, or an Enumeration.

The `Vector` you're providing as the parameter however isn't one of the mentioned types. `Vector.toArray()` however does provide an `Object[]`. Therefore, I would try the following:

```
UnsortedReadableList collection = new UnsortedReadableList();
Vector messages = new Vector();

// ApplicationMessageImpl is simple implementation of 
// net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationMessage interface
messages.addElement(new ApplicationMessageImpl("bla-bla"));
Object[] messageArray = new Object[messages.size()];
messages.copyInto(messageArray));
collection.loadFrom(messageArray);
```

Comment: But this is working, when I converted `Vector` to `Object[]`. For this reason I accept your answer

Comment: Glad to hear it's working, thanks. I'll update the answer accordingly.